# Modelling the data as an AR or MA model?

Tags: time-series, arima, model-selection, autoregressive, moving-average

I am trying to determine whether the data in the screen shot can be modelled as an AR or MA process, I initially thought it was an MA model of order 2 however the partial autocorrelation function between lag 90-100 is throwing me off. Any ideas?[image]

Note: The data has been differenced and the autocorrelation has been calculated.

Comment: What is the sample size here? If it is just over 100, then the lags 90-100 may essentially be picking up noise due to the very small sample size for estimating them.

Comment: I am using a data set that is a 195 x 2 matrix. The first column is the year and the second column contains the wages of its corresponding year. Appreciate the help!

Comment: With wages over periods of many decades I'd definitely be taking logs then differencing; you don't expect variables like this to have constant variance, but to have variance proportional to the square of the mean (financial quantities like wages move in percentage terms not additively). That should (more or less) help to deal with several other issues as well.